# Transforming XML to XML using XSLT and removing linebreaks for specific elements

Tags: xml, xslt

Hello I have a question related to transforming an input XML to an output XML using XSLT and removing the line breaks and indents just for some of the elements.

I would like to illustrate my question:

Input:

```
<LISTESTOF>
  <ICSGROUP>
    <ICSNUM>1</ICSNUM>
    <ICSDKNAME>A1</ICSDKNAME>
    <ICSUKNAME>B2</ICSUKNAME>
  </ICSGROUP>
  <ICSGROUP>
    <ICSNUM>2</ICSNUM>
    <ICSDKNAME>B1</ICSDKNAME>
    <ICSUKNAME>B2</ICSUKNAME>
  </ICSGROUP>
</LISTESTOF>
```

Output:

```
<LISTESTOF>
<ICSGROUP><ICSNUM>1</ICSNUM>
<ICSDKNAME>A1</ICSDKNAME>
<ICSUKNAME>B2</ICSUKNAME></ICSGROUP>
<ICSGROUP><ICSNUM>2</ICSNUM>
<ICSDKNAME>B1</ICSDKNAME>
<ICSUKNAME>B2</ICSUKNAME></ICSGROUP>
</LISTESTOF>
```

My XSLT file so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="LISTESTOF">
             <xsl:value-of select="'&#xA;'" /><LISTESTOF><xsl:apply-templates select="ICSGROUP"/></LISTESTOF>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ICSGROUP">
              <xsl:value-of select="'&#xA;'" /><ICSGROUP><xsl:apply-templates select="ICSNUM"/><xsl:value-of select="'&#xA;'" /><xsl:apply-templates select="ICSDKNAME"/><xsl:value-of select="'&#xA;'" /><xsl:apply-templates select="ICSUKNAME"/></ICSGROUP>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ICSNUM">
        <ICSNUM><xsl:value-of select="."/></ICSNUM>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ICSDKNAME">
        <ICSDKNAME><xsl:value-of select="."/></ICSDKNAME>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ICSUKNAME">
        <ICSUKNAME><xsl:value-of select="."/></ICSUKNAME>
    </xsl:template>


    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Is there a cleaner solution? What will happen with not defined elements? Will they disappear? Any suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Comment: It might be easier to use a dedicated pretty-printer such as http://www.kitebird.com/software/xmlformat/.

Comment: You are right, it will much more easier. But my customer doesn't want to use external software in order to import his xml data to the InDesign document. InDesign have the functionality to use an external xslt file to transform the input-xml during the import process. So I am somehow locked with the xslt language and its possibilities :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start by removing *all* whitespace-only text nodes

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

Then have an identity template to copy everything from input to output unchanged (after the stripping of whitespace) unless otherwise specified

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="ident">
  <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Now add specific templates for the elements you want to *precede* with a newline

```
<xsl:template match="ICSGROUP|ICSDKNAME|ICSUKNAME">
  <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:call-template name="ident"/>
</xsl:template>
```

And a special one for `LISTESTOF` to add an extra newline before the closing tag

```
<xsl:template match="LISTESTOF">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```